# update the details in my JSONB datatypes in sequelize + postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

How can I update the details in my JSONB datatypes in sequelize + postgres? This is what I have been able to do so far... I want a scenario where users can register for a business and also input their location and within the locatri

```
`// update Business controller
import db from '../models';

const business = db.Business;

class UpdateBusiness{
    static updateBusiness(req, res){
        business.sync({force: false}).then(
            () => {
              const location = JSON.stringify({
                address: req.body.address,
                city: req.body.city,
                country: req.body.country,
                state: req.body.state
              });
              business.findAll({
                  where: {
                    id: req.params.businessId,
                    userId: req.decoded.userId,
                    location: {
                        $contains: location
                    } 
                  }
              }).then(businesses => {
                    if(!businesses){
                        return res.status(404).send({
                            message: 'Business does not exist...'
                        })
                    }
                    business
                    .updateAttributes(req.body, { fields: Object.keys(req.body)}, {
                        where: {
                            location: {
                                $contains: location
                            }   
                        }
                    }
              ).then(modifyBusiness => res.status(200).send({
                          modifyBusiness
                      })).catch(error => {
                          return console.log(error.message)
                          res.status(500).send( error.message )
                      })
                }).catch(error => {
                    return console.log(error.message)
                    res.status(500).send( error.message )
                })
            });
    }
}
export default UpdateBusiness;
```

This is the error i got when i run the above code with npm start. I'm just looking for a way to update my jsonB datas when i hit the api..

```
// error that resulted

The server is listening on port 4000
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Businesses" ("id" UUID NOT NULL , "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "mobile" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "email" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "locatio
n" JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}', "category" TEXT NOT NULL, "services" TEXT NOT NULL, "workingHours" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "workingDays" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME
ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "userId" UUID REFERENCES "Users" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("email"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column
_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.
relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Businesses' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "mobile", "email", "location", "category", "services", "workingHours", "workingDays", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId" FROM "Businesses" AS "Busine
ss" WHERE "Business"."id" = 'b020732c-566b-43dd-a7f3-01d982b3810a' AND "Business"."userId" = '8e5317f8-21b9-469a-bfe8-9f0fa764edb3' AND "Business"."location" @> '"{\"address\":\"No 8 saka son
ioki street\",\"city\":\"Ikeja\",\"country\":\"Ghana\",\"state\":\"Lagos\"}"';
businesses.updateAttributes is not a function
```

Comment: Is this all the code in your app? Seems like `businesses.updateAttributes` is somewhere, but not included in your code above. Model hook maybe?

Comment: I've solved it, Thanks... i Figured out that there was an easy way to update jsonb datatypes in sequelize and postgres.